# CSS: preserving box positions on resize?

Tags: css

[image: Before resize]

[image: After resize]

Box 1 contains an image and centered text below it. Box 2 is a set of paragraphs enclosed in a DIV. What rules would I use to make sure that box 2 stays by box 1 whenever the browser window is resized, while making sure the offset W does not change? Thanks!

Comment: did you try clear:both?

Comment: It looks like W is wider in one picture than in the other...

Comment: I'm sorry. W measures from the top edge of the browser window to the top of box 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `margin-top` on the right content div (specified absolutely or by a percentage) and that will ensure that div is always `w` distance away.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JJyat/